# Declare 1st and 2nd digit of a 2-digit number as separate variables

Tags: php, variables, split, integer, digits

I have this code

```
$num = 53;

$num2 = sprintf("%02d", $num);//make sure $num is 2 digits 
$d1 = substr($num2, 1);//get first digit
$d2 = substr($num2, -1);//get second digit
```

`d1` should be `5` and `d2` should be `3` but both of them are `3`. Can someone please tell me why?

Comment: Looks like `substr()` didn't work, can you verify that? Then, check out the documentation to make sure you are actually using it correctly. That said, PHP has a modulo operator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Character index of a string begin with 0, so to get the first char you should use:

```
substr($num2, 0, 1);
```

or

```
$num2[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

Use str_split to split the number in pieces of 1.
That way it's more dynamic than using substr.

```
$num = 53;

$arr = str_split($num);
var_dump($arr);
```

Output:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(1) "5"
  [1]=>
  string(1) "3"
}
```

https://3v4l.org/290UO

Answer (score 0):

`sscanf()` can isolate the two digits as separate variables AND it can explicitly cast each value as integer type.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/vrf1Q))

```
$num = 53;
sscanf($num, '%1d%1d', $d1, $d2);
var_export([$d1, $d2]);
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 5,
  1 => 3,
)
```

Trying to use offsets on an integer value will not work and with fire Warnings.  Using `str_split()` or `substr()` will return string-type values.

---

Your coding attempt didn't work because you never managed to access the first digit that has a `0` offset.

```
53
 ^--- offset 1
^---- offset 0
```

`substr($num2, 1)` means
return from offset 1 onward

`substr($num2, -1)` means return from the last offset (1) onward

Both expressions are targetting offset 1, so both return `3`.